# How to insert a line break in a concatenated cell in Excel 2003

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2003

In Microsoft Excel 2003, I use the following formula [in cell A2 in a sheet named (Allocation)] to refer to several cells from a sheet named (02Mis)

```
='02Mis'!$A$4&"/"&'02Mis'!$A$11&"/"&'02Mis'!$A$10&"/"&'02Mis'!$A$9&"/"&'02Mis'!$A$13
```

as shown in the following images.

[image]
[image]

My question is: how to make each entry appears in a separate line as shown in cell C2 in the top image instead of separated by `/` as in cell A2.

I mean how to make the separator `a new line` instead of `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved in quite a few clicks if you follow these steps.

You have a worksheet named "02Mis" just like this sample:

[image]

And another worksheet in the same workbook named "Allocation" where you extract the required values at **A2** using this:

`='02Mis'!$A$4&"/"&'02Mis'!$A$11&"/"&'02Mis'!$A$10&"/"&'02Mis'!$A$9&"/"&'02Mis'!$A$13`

which results in a long string of text with `/` in between.

To get rid of this and to get a new line for each of the `/` in **C2**, paste this in **C2** and hit 'enter':

`='02Mis'!$A$4&CHAR(10)&'02Mis'!$A$11&CHAR(10)&'02Mis'!$A$10&CHAR(10)&'02Mis'!$A$9&CHAR(10)&'02Mis'!$A$13`

which will fetch you something like this it is not yet the result you desired for:

[image]

Now, after entering the formula in **C2**, select it giving a left click, click on `wrap text` and there you will have it:

[image]

I hope this helps :)

Comment: @Sanu_012.Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use `char(10)` for line return, in combination with clicking on **Wrap Text**.

Note that you could simplify the formula with `TEXTJOIN`, like this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,M4:M10)
```

This is what I got:

[image: example]

If your cells are not sequential, you can separate sequences of cells with `,`:

[image: non sequential cells]

Comment: @Jean-Francois.Thank you for your answer. I need to concatenate cells which are not sequential. I mean M4,M7,M10. How to modify your code instead of M4:M10

Comment: See update of my answer